# Finding "C" wire on old heat pump HVAC unit

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I am wanting to replace my old round mercury filled Honeywell thermostat with a new wifi smart Honeywell thermostat, the only problems is I don't have a "C" wire on my current thermostat and need help finding my "c" wire. I looked at my wiring diagram and it appears to me that the "c" wire is just not being used. I have attached a picture with blue arrow pointing to what I feel is the "c" wire on the wiring diagram and what i feel is the "c" wire in the actual wiring. I am hoping that someone with more HVAC experience can verify this. 
[image: Wire Diagram]
[image: Wires]

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted wire is ***NOT*** the `C` wire.

If you read *Note 3* it says "*Transformer factory wired for 240 volts. Use red and blue leads for 208 volt applications*".  The only time you'd use that blue wire, is if the system feeding the furnace was a 208 volt electrical system.

If you look at the other side of the transformer in the schematic (labeled 24V), you'll see two yellow wires.  One is `R`, while the other is `C`.

[image]